# Datatables server-side how to handle unexisting columns

Tags: flask, datatables, server-side

I am using datatables with server side. My server sends me columns and data.
My data is quite complex having lists and dicts. The columns are coming from an AVRO schema and the data from Kafka messages. Sometimes data is missing. In this case datatables gives me a warning.

```
DataTables warning: table id=records_MODEM_CONFIG - Requested unknown parameter 'mgMigration.peerMGID' for row 0, column 60.
```

Is there a way to have datatables just ignore those column (does not need to be shown) or do I have to add fake data?
Except for the warning the rest is working fine.

The amount of columns (ranging from 10 to 300) and data (over 500.000) make it very difficult and CPU consuming to either reduce the columns based on the record set or enhance the records with empty data for the columns.